# How to rebuild global list

Tags: vagrant

I got an error message when using vagrant command before, so I uninstall the vagrant software, and delete all related files on windows, include C:\Users\user.vagrant.d, but I keep all the folders with Vagrantfile, and then I reinstalled Vagrant, go to the vagrant folder and vagrant up is back to normal, but vagrant global-status can't find anything, could it be rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

hum, maybe you should have backed-up the `C:\Users\user.vagrant.d`. `vagrant global-status` is reading from file `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index` this is a json file with all the information about current machines and their states.

If you do not have a backup you can still try to create it again but it might not be so easy. The part for a given machine is like

```
    "eab6354e4832436e8e7ca8df2ad780f4": {
        "extra_data": {
            "box": {
                "name": "puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-puppet",
                "provider": "virtualbox",
                "version": "1.0.3"
            }
        },
        "local_data_path": "/Users/fhenri/project/vagrant/nginx-loadbalancer/.vagrant",
        "name": "load_balancer",
        "provider": "virtualbox",
        "state": "poweroff",
        "updated_at": null,
        "vagrantfile_name": null,
        "vagrantfile_path": "/Users/fhenri/project/vagrant/nginx-loadbalancer"
    }
```

The id is the vagrant uuid (not the virtualbox id) so you can read the file in `index_uuid` (in my example its `/Users/fhenri/project/vagrant/nginx-loadbalancer/.vagrant/machines/load_balancer/virtualbox/index_uuid`)

Comment: I deleted it because the command did not work even I uninstall and reinstall vagrant and VirtualBox many times, it always show `invalid byte sequence in CP950` till I delete this folder and reinstall vagrant

Comment: clear but if you dont have a backup of the index file and you want vagrant global-status to run you will need to create it yourself or go to each of your vagrant project and run vagrant up (which will update the index file)